Order dataframe within pivot_wider function?
I have a dataframe in a longlist format with duplicate IDs. Each ID has a so-called donornr and timepoint (Tijdspunt). One ID (Deelnemernr.) can have duplicate timepoints like so:
  Deelnemernr. donornrs_pbmc Tijdspunt
   <chr>        <chr>         <chr>    
 1 449132       4491321       T1       
 2 449513       4495131       T1       
 3 449423       4494232       T2       
 4 449460       4494602       T2       
 5 449088       4490882       T2       
 6 449134       4491343       T3       
 7 449106       4491063       T3       
 8 449468       44946852      T5       
 9 449132       4491321       T1       
10 449513       4495131       T1       
11 449423       4494232       T2       
12 449460       4494602       T2       
13 449088       4490882       T2       
14 449134       4491343       T3       
15 449106       4491063       T3       
16 449468       44946852      T5   

I would like to create a wide list from this dataframe. I have used the following code to do so:
pbmc_total <- pbmc_total %>% group_by(Deelnemernr.) %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Deelnemernr.,id)) %>%
  mutate(name=paste0(name,'.',id)) %>% select(-id) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value)

This gives me the following dataframe:
  Deelnemernr. donornrs_pbmc.1 Tijdspunt.1 donornrs_pbmc.2 Tijdspunt.2
  <chr>        <chr>           <chr>       <chr>           <chr>      
1 449132       4491321         T1          4491321         T1         
2 449513       4495131         T1          4495131         T1         
3 449423       4494232         T2          4494232         T2         
4 449460       4494602         T2          4494602         T2         
5 449088       4490882         T2          4490882         T2         
6 449134       4491343         T3          4491343         T3         
7 449106       4491063         T3          4491063         T3         
8 449468       44946852        T5          44946852        T5   

I only gave part of the dataframe but it consists of about 2300 rows and I would the widelist to have a certain order based on the 'Tijdspunt' column. I only want one timepoint per column. This is my desired output:
Deelnemernr. donornrs_pbmc.1 Tijdspunt.1 donornrs_pbmc.2 Tijdspunt.2 donornrs_pbmc.3 Tijdspunt.3 
  <chr>        <chr>           <chr>       <chr>           <chr>      <chr>           <chr>
1 449132       4491321         T1          4491321         T1         NA              NA
2 449513       4495131         T1          4495131         T1         NA              NA
3 449423       NA          NA              NA              NA         4494232         T2 
4 449460       NA          NA              NA              NA         4494602         T2                      
5 449088       NA          NA              NA              NA         NA              NA         
6 449134       NA          NA              NA              NA         NA              NA 
7 449106       NA          NA              NA              NA         NA              NA 
8 449468       NA          NA              NA              NA         NA              NA 


# your example data frame
pmbc_total <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Deelnemernr., ~donornrs_pbmc, ~Tijdspunt,
  "449132",       "4491321",       "T1",       
  "449513",       "4495131",       "T1",       
  "449423",       "4494232",       "T2",       
  "449460",       "4494602",       "T2",       
  "449088",       "4490882",       "T2",       
  "449134",       "4491343",       "T3",       
  "449106",       "4491063",       "T3",       
  "449468",       "44946852",      "T5",       
  "449132",       "4491321",       "T1",       
  "449513",       "4495131",       "T1",       
  "449423",       "4494232",       "T2",       
  "449460",       "4494602",       "T2",       
  "449088",       "4490882",       "T2",       
  "449134",       "4491343",       "T3",       
  "449106",       "4491063",       "T3",       
  "449468",       "44946852",      "T5"   
)

The column names don't exactly match what you had in your desired output example, but the values should be consistent:
pmbc_total |>
  group_by(donornrs_pbmc, Tijdspunt) |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Deelnemernr., names_from = c(Tijdspunt, id), values_from = c(donornrs_pbmc, Tijdspunt), names_sort = TRUE, names_vary = "slowest")

